# Android: Pass text from Textview when clicking an Image button inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

So I have a recycler view with 2 texts and 1 image button. I want to click the image button and then open a new activity and transfering the text from the `textViewADV1` to the next activity

My items .xml in my recyclerview consist of the following

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="openActivity2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewADV1"
        android:text="Line 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewADV2"
        android:text="Line 2"/>
```

My openActivity2() from Main Activity

```
public void openActivity2(View view)
        {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(AdvancedResults.this,OpenSelectedAdvanced.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
```

I tried doing `textViewADV1.getText().toString()` but it only reads the text from the first item in the recycler view

My recycler adapter

```
public class AdvancedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdvancedAdapter.AdvancedViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AdvancedItem> mAdvancedList;
```

public String mImage;

```
    public static class AdvancedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageButton mImagebtn;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public AdvancedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImagebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonADV);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewADV1);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewADV2);
        }
    }

    public AdvancedAdapter(ArrayList<AdvancedItem> advancedList) {
        mAdvancedList = advancedList;
    }

    @Override
    public AdvancedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.advanced_item, parent, false);
        AdvancedViewHolder evh = new AdvancedViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdvancedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AdvancedItem currentItem = mAdvancedList.get(position);
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
        mImage = "www.testImageURL.com";
        Picasso.get().load(mImage).into(holder.mImagebtn);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAdvancedList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all pass a `context` to your `adapter` when you initialize it:**

```
//in the main activity that you initialize the adapter in

AdvancedAdapter adapter = new AdvancedAdapter(your_list , MainActivity.this);
```

**Now change the constructor of `AdvancedAdapter` to accept `context`**

```
 public class AdvancedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdvancedAdapter.AdvancedViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<AdvancedItem> mAdvancedList;

private Context context;

.............

//constructor

public AdvancedAdapter(ArrayList<AdvancedItem> advancedList,Context context) {
mAdvancedList = advancedList;
this.context = context;
}
```

**Now in `onBindViewHolder` in the `AdvancedAdapter`**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdvancedViewHolder holder, int position) {
AdvancedItem currentItem = mAdvancedList.get(position);
holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
mImage = "www.testImageURL.com";
Picasso.get().load(mImage).into(holder.mImagebtn);

//on click image button

hodler.mImagebtn.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

Intent intent = new Intent(context , OpenSelectedAdvanced.class);
intent.putExtra("data" , currentItem.getText1());
context.startActivity(intent);
}

});

}
```

**To get the data from `OpenSelectedAdvanced` activity:**

```
//in oncreate method:

Intent intent = getIntent();

//this is your text view text that came from the clicked image button
String transferedText = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared your ***onBindViewHolder()*** in your adapter class so why are you starting activity from MainActivity. You should add setOnclicklistenr() in onBindViewHolder() to achieve the desired result that you want that is in following way :

```
public class AdvancedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdvancedAdapter.AdvancedViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AdvancedItem> mAdvancedList;
//one more thing you have to create Context field so that you can
 //you can start the activity from any context (From Any activity)
 private Context mContext;

  public String mImage;

public static class AdvancedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder        {
    public ImageButton mImagebtn;
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public TextView mTextView2;

    public AdvancedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImagebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonADV);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewADV1);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewADV2);
    }
}

public AdvancedAdapter(ArrayList<AdvancedItem> advancedList, Context mContext) {
    mAdvancedList = advancedList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public AdvancedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.advanced_item, parent, false);
    AdvancedViewHolder evh = new AdvancedViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdvancedViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AdvancedItem currentItem = mAdvancedList.get(position);
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    mImage = "www.testImageURL.com";
    holder.mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Here You start your activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity2.class);
            //you can putExtras here
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
    });
    Picasso.get().load(mImage).into(holder.mImagebtn);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mAdvancedList.size();
}
   }
```

Now initialize this adapter in your activity where you implemented recyclerView And Send that arraylist into the parameters of that constructor of your adapter :) if did not understand yet you can try the tutorial on the link given below : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIppSKk9afI

Comment: I was hoping i'd be easier doing it from the main activity, I've added my adapter if it helps

Comment: and then how do I get the text from the TextView using the position?

Comment: You are setting the textView using Arraylist<AdvancedItem> send using this.

Comment: AdvancedItem has Constructor and getter and setter ? If you are beginner then first try to go for a tutorial you may go to the link or you can google for the tutorial.